# Confusion about the use of 'quite' in 'quite a bit', 'quite a few', and 'quite a lot'

Tags: grammar

I have a hard time understanding some definitions and usage of [***quite***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quite) in English Grammar Today (via Cambridge Dictionaries Online). The explanation is as follows:

> #### *Quite a bit, quite a few, quite a lot*
>
> We often use quite with *a bit*, *a few* and *a lot* to refer to large amounts and quantities:
>
> *You should ask Mez for some advice. He knows **quite a bit** about gardening.*

(I don't know if he knows a lot or a little about gardening, because of *a bit* is used here.)

> **A:** *We bought **quite a lot** of new furniture, didn’t we?*
>   **B:** *Yeah, **quite a bit**.*

(Do *quite a lot* and *quite a bit* suggest the same meaning? Does *quite a bit* mean "very little"?)

> *There were **quite a few** of us at the meeting.*

(What does *quite a few* mean? Does it mean "very little"?)

> We also use *quite a bit* and *quite a lot* to mean ‘often’:
>
> *Do you come here **quite a bit**?*

(Do *quite a bit, quite a lot*, and *quit a few* have the same meaning in this context? If Not, why?)

> *I used to go sailing **quite a lot***.

(Can we use *quite a bit* or *quite a few* here without changing the meaning of this sentence?)

---

> #### *Quite* + *a lot /a bit* + comparatives

We often use *quite a lot* and *quite a bit* with a comparative adjective or adverb to mean ‘much’:

> *We went to Italy when I was **quite a bit** younger.*

(Can we use *quite a lot* or *quite a few* here without changing the meaning of the sentence?)

> *The new truck is **quite a lot** heavier than the old model.*

(Can we use *quite a bit* and *quite a few* here without changing the meaning of sentence?)

Answer (score 8):

"Quite a bit" and "quite a lot" do mean the same thing.  The difference is that "quite a bit" uses "a bit" ironically (saying the opposite of the truth) or in understatement (saying something is less in number or importance than it actually is), while "quite a lot" is literal.

The usage of the three sayings, "quite a bit", "quite a few", and "quite a lot", also differs:

- "Quite a bit" means that you have a lot of something. It can be used to say something is in greater quantity, for example: "I have quite a bit of work to do today." In this example "bit" is the subject described as being "of work.
- "Quite a few" also means you have a lot of something, but specifically quantity. You could say: "I own quite a few pencils", or "We moved quite a few pieces of furniture." "Few" is not the noun, and the phrase must be followed by a noun.
- "Quite a lot", just like the previous two, means you have a lot of something. It can be used wherever you could just say "a lot" by itself. For example, you could say "I have a lot of bananas", or you could say "I have quite a lot of bananas". "Quite a lot of bananas" is more than "a lot of bananas"

Comment: I don't hear anything sarcastic in "quite a bit". It does have a very different meaning from "a bit", but that is the nature of idiom.

Comment: @ColinFine I suppose ironically is better than sarcastically... In essence, it is _not_ a bit.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer with interpretation of those two sentences ? And what about. Quite a  few ? And what is saracastically or understantement ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma "Quite a bit", "Quite a lot",  and "Quite a few" all mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.  Sarcastically refers to saying the opposite of what is meant: you may say you have "quite a few" of something, but you actually have many.  Understatement would be saying that something is less in number or importance than it actually is: again, saying you have "a few" when in reality you have many.

Comment: Do you mean 'quite a few' and 'quite a bit' refers to something small quentity and 'quite a lot' refers to'large amount or quentity?    But the definition says : We often use quite with a bit, a few and a lot to refer to large amounts and quantities. I'm confused about it.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Both refer to a large quantity.  The differences between them are small, and do not really matter when using them in everyday speech.

Comment: It would be better if you could raise or explore the difference between them so that i would be able to use them correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39230/discussion-between-yubraj-sharma-and-scott-mikutsky).

Comment: Considering your answer, it would seem that they are idioms, aren't they?

Comment: @yubrajsharma Yes, they are idioms.

Answer (score 3):

*Quite a bit, quite a lot* and  *quite a few* all mean:

- a large amount, but not a very, very large amount

When the stress is on *quite* it emphasises *not a very very large amount*. Otherwise and especially when the strongest stress is on the last word (*bit, lot, few*), it emphasises the *large amount* part of the meaning:

- Bob says you know a lot about gardening
- I know *quite* a lot.

Here the speaker is emphasising that they don't know a very, very large amount.

- Bob says you know about gardening.
- Yes I know quite a *lot*.

Here the speaker is emphasising that they know a large amount.

---

The word *quite* is used in this way in many types of sentence. For example look at the following sentence about running:

- I am *quite* fast.

This means that I am not very, very fast. I am not Usain Bolt! Compare that with:

- I am quite *fast*.

This means that I am definitely fast.

Comment: Hello! I'm not quite following this answer  although it has helped rather a bit (I take it *rather* functions the same way as *quite* here). My lack of understanding flows from your seeming emphasis that either *quite* or the other word (bit, lot, few) is usually or often emphasized when the phrase is used, but in my experience as a native speaker of American English such phrases are said with "even" stress,  without stressing either *quite* or the other word. Could you speak to this? Or am I misunderstanding your meaning?

Comment: As an example, 95% of the time I would read or say *I am quite fast* as not emphasizing anything (neither *quite* nor *fast*). So I would find the meaning in the unstressed phrase as a whole and not on a stressed portion. The same for *quite a bit*, etc.

Comment: @AlanCarmack You may have missed the "otherwise and especially if" part of the answer - which indicates that there may be no marked stress. However, this answer is slightly simplified for learners who don't know a lot about pronunciation. If I was writing for ELU, or a pron student, then what it would say is that when the nucleus falls on *quite* (because the *bit/lot/few* has become deaccented and moved out of focus), then *quite* takes on contrastive stress where it contrasts with some already mentioned idea of a large amount ...

Comment: @AlanCarmack However, if the nucleus falls on the last word, then it just gives the idea of a large amount. When the pitch movement involved in the nuceus is very marked this idea is being emphasised.

Comment: Do you mean 'quite a few' and 'quite a bit' refers to something small quentity and 'quite a lot' refers to'large amount or quentity?    But the definition says : We often use quite with a bit, a few and a lot to refer to large amounts and quantities. I'm confused about it.

Comment: @yubrajsharma No. *quite a bit* has nothing to do with a small quantity. It refers to a large quantity. All three mean *a large quantity* or *a large amount*. None of these phrases means *a small amount*.

Comment: Well, you would mean to say that 'quite a bit'  few or lot are all used to talk about large amount, are they idioms ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma You could think of them as idioms, yes :)

Comment: Can i say ?
*i've quite a lot/bit of money to buy a car.
*your answer is quite a detailed.( to mean very detailed)

Comment: @yubrajsharma Yes and yes!