# What is the difference between 'Quite' and 'Very' in the following sentences?

Tags: word-difference

> - She is **very** lovely.
> - She is **quite** a lovely girl.

> - He is **very** handsome.
> - He is **quite** a handsome man.

Do they mean exactly the same? What i know and found on the internet is that "the effect of very is stronger than the effect of quite"

Comment: Did you search in the dictionaries the definition for "quite" and "very"? What did you find? Without showing your efforts and your understanding of the problem, we cannot help.

Comment: Related question [quite a bit, quite a lot Vs very](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/98346/9161)

Comment: Note that “quite” is used differently in BrE and AmE.

Answer (score 2):

Very is an adverb used to intensify. Quite is an adverb used to dampen a little. If you say “she is very lovely,” you are signaling to your audience to envision a lovely girl, then dial it up a bit. If you say “she is quite lovely,” you are signaling to your audience to picture a lovely girl, but dial back your expectations just a bit. The one caveat is that quite is often used not because the girl isn’t just plain lovely or even very lovely, but as deliberate understatement.

Comment: I'm assuming the understated usage of *quite* is the BrE usage and the synonym for *very* is the AmE usage?

Answer (score 1):

As StephenS wrote, the meaning and use of "quite" are different in the US and in the UK.  In the US, *quite* is an intensifier, so that "quite pretty" is much stronger than  "pretty."   For me, it is a synonym for "very." When used directly before an adjective, it is more often used by women than by men (in the US).

(I don't have a reference for my views; they are based on my experience as a native speaker of American English and over two decades as an EFL teacher.  The Britannica discussion reflects British English.)

Answer (score 0):

The word **very** shows more intensity than the word **quite**. You can find the complete explanation and reasoning [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/pretty-fairly-really-very-and-quite).

Also, quite can both mean *very* as well as, in some cases, *slightly*. ([Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=quite&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&oq=quite&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2079j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))